# XML разметка в Android-приложении

Tags: java, android, xml

Как мне распределить объекты так, чтобы TextView находился идеально посередине родительского объекта, а ImageButton слева. Пробовал устанавливать для родительского элемента

```
android:gravity="center"
```

, а также для самого TextView

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

, но ничего не выходит. Прилагаю код ниже.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".add">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backArrow"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/tenor_sans"
            android:text="@string/adder"
            android:textColor="#2C1E4D"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Используйте FrameLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вариант с RelativeLayout можно сделать так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="#2C1E4D"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вариант с constraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!